# jquery mobile change event dosn't work on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, mobile

I have 2 input fields and want them to change two different fields:

```
$(document).on('change','#test', function(event) { 
    var value1 = (+$(glas1).val() * 3);
    $("#txt1").val(value1); 
});

$(document).on('change','#test', function(event){ 
    var value2 = (+$(glas2).val() * 5);
    $("#txt2").val(value2); 
});
```

My form name is test. It works in Chrome and on iPhone. But it doesn't work in IE? Why...

Comment: Which version of IE and What kind of error it gives in IE?

Comment: which version of jQuery library are you using ? 2.x don't support below IE-9

Comment: IE 11, and I am using jQuery 1.9.1 and Mobil 1.3.2.

Comment: My bad... the problem is that the input fields are inside at FORM. When <form> is removed - IE has no problems.

Comment: But the question is still, how do I get this to work: http://jsfiddle.net/gVQa8/
It works in Chrome... and if you remove the FORM, it also works in IE. But I need the FORM :-)

Comment: Solved: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20409732/2996395