# jQuery Mobile change value in form dosen't work in IE

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer, mobile, input

This Fiddle works fine in Chrome, but not in IE.

jsfiddle.net/gVQa8

Only if you remove the surrounding FORM, it will work in IE. But I need the FORM :-)

I've also tried using ID instead of class - but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
http://jsfiddle.net/gVQa8/22/
```

I just needed to write:

```
"#glas1"
```

and not just

```
glas1
```

to call the ID!